# executing a class with a -cp and class is not found

Tags: java, classpath

I just started learning Java. Using Linux, which is important to tell because of the colon and semicolon. I searched the site, but did not find the answer.

java version is 1.7

working directory is /home/jutreni/Poglavlje01/Vjezbe

java file V0101.java is in that folder, so it's path is /home/jutreni/Poglavlje01/Vjezbe/V0101.java

V0101.java:

```
/*
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of version 3 of the GNU General Public License as published
 * by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 */
package Poglavlje01.Vjezbe;


public class V0101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("HyWorld zadaci");
    }
}
```

I need to execute that java with -cp option

so i did:

```
cd /home/jutreni/Poglavlje01/Vjezbe
```

then compiled the java file

```
javac V0101.java
```

and got V0101.class in the same folder.

I then tried to execute java -cp with

```
java -cp /home/jutreni/Poglavlje01/Vjezbe Poglavlje01.Vjezbe:V0101
```

and got error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Poglavlje01.Vjezbe:V0101
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`java -cp /home/jutreni Poglavlje01.Vjezbe.V0101`

Since this is the "cannonical name" of your class: `Poglavlje01.Vjezbe.V0101`, and this is where Java should start looking for classes by their cannonical names: `/home/jutreni`, so we're putting it in the classpath.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked. If You have another minute...what do you mean by "cannonical name"? And also...how can I mark this solved? It asks me some reputation credits to vote up Your answer.

Comment: Basically, it's a "qualified" name of the class, that includes the package. It's used to avoid name collision between classes of different packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
java -cp /home/jutreni/Poglavlje01/Vjezbe Poglavlje01.Vjezbe:V0101
```

to this:

```
java -cp /home/jutreni/Poglavlje01/Vjezbe Poglavlje01.Vjezbe.V0101
```

Comment: Also, by Java convention, package names should be all-lower-case

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class Poglavlje01.Vjezbe.V0101